# pod in Kubernetes cluster is unable to connect to internet with egress networkpolicy

Tags: kubernetes-pod

I have deployed a vendor container in an on-prem Kubernetes cluster and the container in the pod needs to connect to internet to validate license and few other details. I have checked the environment and I don't see any existing network policies in the cluster and/or pod level.
I then added below networkpolicy entry for the pod namespace but still seeing following error in pods and service log.

> level=fatal msg="Unable to connect to the license server"

.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
 name: allow-ingress-egress
 namespace: myappns
spec:
 podSelector:
 matchLabels: {}
 egress:
 - {}
 policyTypes:
 - Ingress
 - Egress
 ingress: 
 - {}
 egress: 
 - {}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realized that by default pod to pod and egress communication is allowed from all the pods in Kubernetes cluster. Maybe it was a temp network issue when I was testing, external/egress connections are working fine without any network policy rules in place. I am aware that this is not ideal for production environments, so will work on that part.